# PS 2.0 versus PS 5.0 issues and empty Data Arrays - how to fix

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an issue with Powershell version 2.0 and I am limited to using it for the below purpose.

I am trying to manipulate certain files using the following code:
But in version 2.0 when I pipe a PScustomobject data array into another array the array looks empty but there is a count in the array?

Basicly I need to delete files once I have the source file to delete and the below code works no problem in PS: 5.0 but 2.0 is giving me the above issue's.

```
$allowedExtensions = @("*.JPEG", "*.JPG", "*.PDF", "*.PPT", "*.DOCX", "*.XLSX", "*.XLS", "*.RTF", "*.PPTX", "*.DOC", "*.BMP", "*.PNG", "*.TXT", "*.ZIP", "*.XLSM")
$filteredfiles = @()
$sourcefiles = @()
$allsrcfiles = @()

            # Get files with the specified extensions within the project folder and its subfolders
            $sourcefiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $projectFolder.FullName -File -Recurse -Include $allowedExtensions #-Exclude $excludedFolders
            
            $filteredfiles = $sourcefiles | Select-Object Name, FullName

            If ($filteredfiles -ne $null)   
            {
            $filteredfiles | Export-Csv -Path $csvfilteredfiles -NoTypeInformation
            }
            
            foreach ($file in $filteredfiles) 
            {
                # Check if the FullName length is greater than 1 char
                if ($file.FullName.Length -gt 1) 
                {
                
                    ###Get entire source file path  
                    $sourceFilePath = $file.FullName

                    ###Code removed for brevity               

                    #Capture data in array object 
                    $logEntry = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Filename = $file.name
                    SourcefilePath = $sourceFilePath
                    }
                    ####This is the data array that gets used to delete files below!
                    $allsrcfiles += $logEntry                    
                }
            }

            #$deletefiles = $copylogs | Select-Object Filename, sourcefilePath
                $deletefiles = $allsrcfiles | Select-Object Filename, SourcefilePath
                ####CHECK!!!!!!  IN PS5.0 This data array populates 
                ##IN PS:2.0 this array  $deletefiles is empty!
                
                If ($deletefiles -ne $null)
                {
                Write-Host "Now removing copied file from: $sourcefolder"
                ForEach ($filedel in $deletefiles)
                {
                $filetoremove = $filedel.Filename
                $removepathfile = $filedel.sourcefilePath
                $srcdir = Split-Path -Parent $removepathfile

                    try
                    {
                        Write-Host "Removing: $filetoremove from  $srcdir ........"
                        Remove-Item -Path $removepathfile -Force -WhatIf
                        Write-Host "Removed file name: $removepathfile" -BackgroundColor Green
                        $deletelog = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Filename = $filetoremove
                        SourceDirectory = $srcdir
                        Filepath =  $removepathfile
                        Deleted = "Yes"}
                        $deletelogs += $deletelog
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Write-Host "Problem Deleting file:  $removepathfile" -BackgroundColor Red
                        $errorcatch = $_.Exception.ToString()
                        Write-Host "$errorcatch"
                    }
               }
               }
```

The deleted files array looks like this:

$deletefiles

Filename                                                            SourcefilePath

---

NOTHING

In powershell 5.0 this is not an issue.

Can someone help with this issue.

Comment: The `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntax requires v3+. In v2, you need to use `New-Object`, which doesn't guarantee property order, however. To ensure the desired property order in v2, you'll have to (inefficiently) construct the object property by property, using `Add-Member` calls.

Comment: Ah,  I've used New-Object property before.  Where would the add member bit go?

Comment: You use a lot of unnecessary auxiliary variables and you run two independent loops over basically the same file system objects. I'd recommend to simplify your code. Keep it simple! ‍♂️

Comment: @IainHoward: The PSv2 equivalent of the following PSv3+ `[pscustomobject]` literal:
`$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ Foo = 'Bar'; Baz = 'Qux' }`
is the following:
`$obj = New-Object PsObject;
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Foo -Value 'Bar';
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Baz -Value 'Qux'`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to export the data to CSV which I was doing anyway,  And use that very same data to do a CSV-IMPORT unto the array and it's no longer empty:

The solution code is as follows:

The modified code has been marked up.  ###NEW CODE SOLUTION!####

```
$allowedExtensions = @("*.JPEG", "*.JPG", "*.PDF", "*.PPT", "*.DOCX", "*.XLSX", "*.XLS", "*.RTF", "*.PPTX", "*.DOC", "*.BMP", "*.PNG", "*.TXT", "*.ZIP", "*.XLSM")
$filteredfiles = @()
$sourcefiles = @()
$allsrcfiles = @()

$csvlogdata = @()
$csvHeader = "Filename,SourcefilePath"

            # Get files with the specified extensions within the project folder and its subfolders
            $sourcefiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $projectFolder.FullName -File -Recurse -Include $allowedExtensions #-Exclude $excludedFolders
            
            $filteredfiles = $sourcefiles | Select-Object Name, FullName

            If ($filteredfiles -ne $null)   
            {
            $filteredfiles | Export-Csv -Path $csvfilteredfiles -NoTypeInformation
            }
            
            foreach ($file in $filteredfiles) 
            {
                # Check if the FullName length is greater than 1 char
                if ($file.FullName.Length -gt 1) 
                {
                
                    ###Get entire source file path  
                    $sourceFilePath = $file.FullName

                    ###Code removed for brevity               

                    #Capture data in array object 
                    $logEntry = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Filename = $file.name
                    SourcefilePath = $sourceFilePath
                    }
                    ####This is the data array that gets used to delete files below!
                    $allsrcfiles += $logEntry                    
                }
            }
                
                
                ###NEW CODE SOLUTION!####
                # Loop through your PSCustomObject entries and format them as CSV lines ised for PS2.0
                foreach ($Entry in $allsrcfiles) {
                    $csvLine = '"{0}","{1}"' -f $Entry.Filename, $Entry.SourcefilePath
                    $csvlogdata += $csvLine
                }

                # Write the CSV header and data to the CSV file
                $csvHeader | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\deletefile.csv" -Encoding ASCII
                $csvcopylogdata | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\deletefile.csv" -Append -Encoding ASCII

                ###OLD CODE that did not work:
                #$deletefiles = $allsrcfiles | Select-Object Filename, sourcefilePath
                
                
                $deletefiles = Import-CSV -Path "c:\temp\deletefile.csv"
                ###NEW CODE SOLUTION!####  COMPLETE
                
                If ($deletefiles -ne $null)
                {
                Write-Host "Now removing copied file from: $sourcefolder"
                ForEach ($filedel in $deletefiles)
                {
                $filetoremove = $filedel.Filename
                $removepathfile = $filedel.sourcefilePath
                $srcdir = Split-Path -Parent $removepathfile

                    try
                    {
                        Write-Host "Removing: $filetoremove from  $srcdir ........"
                        Remove-Item -Path $removepathfile -Force -WhatIf
                        Write-Host "Removed file name: $removepathfile" -BackgroundColor Green
                        $deletelog = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Filename = $filetoremove
                        SourceDirectory = $srcdir
                        Filepath =  $removepathfile
                        Deleted = "Yes"}
                        $deletelogs += $deletelog
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Write-Host "Problem Deleting file:  $removepathfile" -BackgroundColor Red
                        $errorcatch = $_.Exception.ToString()
                        Write-Host "$errorcatch"
                    }
               }
               }
```

Comment: It's commendable that you want to share a solution, but given the amount of incidental code in both your question and this answer, I suspect that not many future readers will benefit.